# Can I run my attic HVAC/Furance without an Air Cleaner/Purifier Filter

Tags: hvac, furnace

I have an Aprilaire 1410 air purifier attached to my attic HVAC/furnace.

Does the air purifier serve the same purpose as a typical air filter in a HVAC/furnace or is it simply *additional* filtering?  Can I run my heat without the purifier filter, temporarily until the proper part gets there?

Or will a typical store bought filter work in place of the Aprilaire accordion style filter?

Answer (score 1):

The Aprilaire 1410 air purifier is a larger, more efficient, longer lasting version of the typical 1 inch filters. I'm not really a fan of these frame-less filters as they can be hard to find locally. You can always get them online and have then in a day or two.

In addition to filtering out fine particles like dust, a filter also protects the HVAC system from larger particles that can damage the fan or condenser coils.  You should not run the system if there are no other filters besides this one.